How to get a List of the Vertices and Edges in self made Catan Game
I tired to program a Catan Game so I can play it with my friends. But I couldn't figure out how get the vertices and edges where the houses and roads will be placed.
//hexagon.ts
export enum FieldType {
    GRAIN,
    BRICK,
    ORE,
    FOREST,
    SHEEP,
    WISH,
    WATER,
    DESERT
}

export class Hexagon {
    public type: FieldType;
    public number: number;

    public xCord: number;
    public yCord: number;

    constructor(fieldType: FieldType, x: number, y: number, number: number) {
        this.type = fieldType;
        this.xCord = x;
        this.yCord = y;
        this.number = number;
    }
}

//game.ts
import { GAMEPHASE } from ".";
import { FieldType, Hexagon } from "./hexagon";
import { MapCords, SeafarersMap } from "./map";
import { seafarersOne } from "./mappresets";
import { Player } from "./player";

export interface Cards {
    brick: number;
    grain: number;
    ore: number;
    wood: number;
    sheep: number;
}

export interface DevelopmentCards {
    robber: number;
    monopoly: number;
    twoRoads: number;
    yearOfPlenty: number;
    victoryPoint: number;
}

export enum GAMEEVENT {
    STARTGAME,
    PLACE_STARTER_HOUSES,
    ROLL_DICE,
    DISCARD_CARDS,
    SKIP_TURN,
    PLACE_ROBBER,
}

export class Game {
    public players: Player[] = [];
    public gamePhase: GAMEPHASE = GAMEPHASE.LOBBY;
    public nextEvent: GAMEEVENT = GAMEEVENT.STARTGAME;
    public activePlayer: number = 0;
    pointsToWin: number;

    public gameCode: number;

    catanBoardWidth = 13;
    catanBoardHeigth = 8;

    public hexagons: Hexagon[] = [];

    public map: SeafarersMap = { ...seafarersOne };

    constructor(gameCode: number, pointsToWin: number) {
        this.gameCode = gameCode;
        this.pointsToWin = pointsToWin;
    }

    public async startGame() {
        console.log(seafarersOne)
        this.activePlayer = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.players.length);
        await this.generateBoard();
        this.nextEvent = GAMEEVENT.ROLL_DICE;
    }

    async generateBoard() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.catanBoardHeigth; i++) {
            for (let u = 0; u < this.catanBoardWidth; u++) {
                let cord: MapCords = {
                    x: u,
                    y: i,
                };

                if (this.map.mainland_coords.some((c) => c.x === cord.x && c.y === cord.y)) {
                    this.hexagons.push(
                        new Hexagon(this.getFieldTypeFromList(this.map.maindland_tiles), u, i, 1)
                    );
                } else if (this.map.island_coords.some((c) => c.x === cord.x && c.y === cord.y)) {
                    this.hexagons.push(
                        new Hexagon(this.getFieldTypeFromList(this.map.island_tiles), u, i, 1)
                    );
                } else {
                    this.hexagons.push(new Hexagon(FieldType.WATER, u, i, 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private getRandomFieldType(): FieldType {
        const validFieldTypes = [
            FieldType.BRICK,
            FieldType.GRAIN,
            FieldType.ORE,
            FieldType.FOREST,
            FieldType.SHEEP,
        ];

        const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * validFieldTypes.length);
        return validFieldTypes[randomIndex];
    }

    private getFieldTypeFromList(list: FieldType[]): FieldType {
        if (list.length === 0) {
            return this.getRandomFieldType();
        }

        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        const element = list[index];

        list.splice(index, 1);

        return element;
    }
}


I also read this article but I still don't have a clue how to work with the vertices and edges.
https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/
